# while ajax running finished it automatically clear the saved value in hiddenfield how to avoid it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

while click the save button i am running the dynamic table in each function inside handler to save the dynamic row upload file after it save i am saving in json the value.

After the value saved in hiddenfield  it clear the hidden field value . its not store in the hidden field.

i need the hiddenfield json value to save in the database

```
   $('#tblPower tbody tr').each(function () {
                        debugger;
                        var stre = $(this).children('td:nth-child(4)').find('input[type="file"]').attr("id");
                        var country = $(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').find('.Country').val() || 0;
                        var validity = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').find('.validity').val() || 0;
                        var clavalidity = $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').find('.clavalidity').val();
                        var POAID = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').find('span').text() || 0;

                        var FileName = "";
                        var uploadfiles = $("#" + stre + "").get(0);
                        var uploadedfiles = uploadfiles.files;
                        var fromdata = new FormData();
                        for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
                            fromdata.append(uploadedfiles[i].name, uploadedfiles[i]);
                        }
                        var choice = {};
                        choice.url = "UploadHandler.ashx";
                        choice.type = "POST";
                        choice.data = fromdata;
                        choice.contentType = false;
                        choice.processData = false;
                        choice.success = function (result) {
                            FileName = result;
                            if (power == '') {
                                power = '{"POAID":"' + POAID + '","Country":"' + country + '","Validity":"' + validity + '","Notes":"' + clavalidity + '","UploadId":"' + stre + '","FileName":"' + FileName + '"}';
                            }
                            else {
                                power += ',{"POAID":"' + POAID + '","Country":"' + country + '","Validity":"' + validity + '","Notes":"' + clavalidity + '","UploadId":"' + stre + '","FileName":"' + FileName + '"}';
                            }
                            power = '[' + power + ']';
                            dynamic(power);
                            **$('#hfAttorney').val(power);**
                        };
                        choice.error = function (err) {
                            alert(err.statusText);
                        };
                        $.ajax(choice);
                    });
```

Comment: 1 - what does `dynamic(power);` do ... 2 - what makes you think `hfAttorney` is "cleared"

Comment: dynamic power is function leave that.. hfAttorney i saved the value in hiddenfield but it clear the value i could not get value in server side

Comment: well, you're filling hidden field after the request is completed, so, you're doing it wrong if you expect the content of the hidden field to be posted in the request, that has already completed

Comment: then how i can get the json value in hidenfield please advice me dear friend

Comment: send it in the request, like you do with all the other `fromdata`

Comment: sorry to ask could you please give the code

Comment: of course, you'll need to change the server side, because `FileName` wont be in the hidden field in the request - but as `FileName` comes from the server, that shouldn't be any problem at all

Comment: wow, you want the code ...move all the "power" stuff just before `$.ajax`, of course, FileName wont be part of it, you'll have to figure out what to do there, and alse add `fromdata.append('hfAttorney', power)` before `$.ajax` but after all the power stuff ... really? How much of that code is yours, you should've been able to figure this out from my comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3cv65fny/

Comment: i tried this but i could not get the fllename because filename is the important

Comment: filename comes from the **response** ... so, you don't need to send it in the **request** - as I said, you'll need to change the server side code because you **can not** send the response as part of the request as this would tear the universe into pieces

Comment: so no possible to send the filename in hiddenfield

Comment: as FileName comes from response, the I guess not, unless you invent time travel :p